# iptables - port 25 not getting traffic even though default policy is ACCEPT and all rules are flushed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables, postfix, smtp

I am having a problem that's driving me up the wall. I have a server, where after several attempts at various iptable rules, I have flushed iptable rules and set default policy to accept.

The output of `$ sudo iptables -L`:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I do have postfix listening on the port as can be found on `$ sudo netstat -tulnp`:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9639/master
```

When I run nmap from my local machine `$ sudo nmap -p 25 <server-ip>`:

```
PORT   STATE    SERVICE
25/tcp filtered smtp
```

When I run nmap from the server itself `$ sudo nmap -p 25 localhost`:

```
PORT   STATE SERVICE
25/tcp open  smtp
```

When I telnet to the server from my local machine, the connection timesout. But if I telnet on the server itself `$ telnet localhost 25` then I see:

```
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 <server-domain> ESMTP Postfix
```

I'm really at my wits end. I found some other posts on this site and other stack-exchange ones about similar issues, but the problem there seemed to be that the service was not running and listening on port 25. But as you can see from the netstat command, the postfix process is listening to port 25 on this server.

Can anyone please give me pointers on what to try next?

Oh also tried `$ sudo tcpdump -n port 25` while the connection attempt was made. But there were no packets captured. But tcpdump captured packets when I connected from the server itself `$ telnet localhost 25`.

Comment: Traffic can be dropped not only in the filter table. Your `iptables -L` does not prove nothing is filtered, and there is also nftables in the Linux, which is controlled elsewhere. Please check `iptables-save` and `nft list ruleset`.

Comment: Try tools like `tcptraceroute` to check if connection is blocked **before** your host.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov `iptables-save` and `nft list ruleset` looks ok to me, in that I see port 25 being allowed in input. And I don't see anything else. Should I post the results in my question?

Comment: @AnFi I tried `tcptraceroute <server-ip> 25` and got a couple of responses between my machine and my router, but after that it was all `* * *`. No responses for 30 hops

Comment: It is quite likely that **outgoing** connections to port 25 are blocked by the ISP.   Check if your postfix accepts connections at port 587 and try to telnet it from test host.

Answer (score 0):

Many ISPs don’t allow SMTP traffic. They block or drop all such traffic.

Contact your ISP or hosting provider to ask whether they allow port 25 traffic.

Comment: While this could be true, reasonable is to block traffic only in outgoing direction: they don't allow *outgoing to tcp/25*, but don't do anything particular in incoming direction. There is no reason to block incoming, since it could do no harm. I'd rather suspect that blockage occurs on the *local* provider from which attempts to test were made.